# Playing something with cvlc on linux via php

Tags: php

i have the following PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_GET["href"]) && isset($_GET["name"])) {
    exec("cvlc " . $_GET["href"] . "  &");
}
```

the href is definitively a valid URL, and the exec function is also called (i tried via echo), also the cvlc command works fine when i type it into the console, however once i run it through the browser, it's just loading forever.

The exec command is also working fine, i just tested it.

*Edit*: The url i tried to play was http://dradio.de/streaming/dlf.m3u, but i tried a few others too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command inserting a double quote to the url:

```
exec("cvlc \"" . $_GET["href"] . "\"  &");
```

(also please note, that this code is vulnerable to RCE, so keep attention!)